# Mathematical notation to expand a list/set of values?

Tags: notation

Is there any mathematical notation to expand a list/set of values?

I am looking for something that would expand like this:

$A=(x=0,x<=3)[2x+1]$

$A=[2(0)+1,2(1)+1,2(2)+1,2(3)+1]$

$A=[1,3,5,7]$

Comment: Maybe
$$
\big[2n+1\big]_{n=0}^3
$$

Comment: A compact notation for the corresponding set would be $2(\Bbb Z\cap [0,3])+ 1$ or $(2\Bbb Z+1)\cap [0,7]$.

Comment: If it is an ordered list, then it is denoted with parentheses: $(2n+1)_{n\in\{0,1,2,3\}}$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the counterpart of sigma or pi notation for sequences is typically notated as $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in S}$ where $a_n$ expresses the $n$'th term and $S$ is an index set. For general sets, a different notation is usually used, called *set builder notation*, which has the form $\left\{x|\phi(x)\right\}$, where $\phi$ is some formula satisfied by the included elements $x$. Depending on the system we are using, there may be some limitations on the sets that are allowed to be built, hence which expressions in this notation are valid.

So, the even numbers, $0,2,4,6,\ldots$, could be expressed in the above notations as an (indexed) sequence as $\left(2n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ or as a (non-indexed) set $\left\{x|\exists y \in \mathbb{N} . x=2y \right\}$.

Answer (score 1):

We use *[finite sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Finite_and_infinite)* to denote such lists:
\begin{align*}
A=\left(2x+1\right)_{0\leq x\leq 3}=(1,3,5,7)
\end{align*}

Comment: It is not clear that $x$ is an integer with this notation

Comment: @LL3.14: It is a common notation. Here $x$ is a bound index variable as well as any other like $n$ or $q$ or $t$. The slight advantage here is to have an expression $2x+1$ which is also stated in OPs question, just to enhance readability.

Comment: Yes, but the same notation is also common for real numbers ... $(2x+1)_{x\in\{0,1,2,3\}}$ would be more standard I think.

Comment: @LL3.14: I can partly agree. The drawback with the set notation is we loose the order property which is also crucial for $n$-tuples. Nevertheless, both notations are commonly in use, since we can often read for example $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ as well as $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$.